# Add session cookie in Postman query

Tags: java, rest, get, postman, session-cookies

I want to submit a GET request against an api endpoint but I dont know how to
add the session cookie so my request is successful 
and I get through the authentication. When I send my request, I get this:

```
{
    "timestamp": "2020-04-07T14:39:56.070+0000",
    "status": 401,
    "error": "Unauthorized",
    "message": "Unauthorized",
    "path": "/api/fridge/recommended-dishes"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to enable cookie interceptor in postman https://learning.postman.com/docs/postman/sending-api-requests/interceptor/

Comment: Thank you, this helps